# Audio recording on iOS using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I've been looking for this for several days, but couldn't find anything clear about how to record audio on iOS using PhoneGap.

Maybe someone had similar problem? Please share your solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're new in the whole Cordova Section, but no problem, you only need some information before you get started.

Cordova is the same as PhoneGap - for more details about that, just google around, you'll find as many information as you need.

Cordova has a bunch of plugins which are available via [node.js](https://nodejs.org/). Creating a project doesn't seem to be a problem for you, but you may need some information on how to install a plugin.

---

**How do i install a Cordova / PhoneGap Plugin?**

1. `cordova create Test com.example.com Test`
2. `cd Test`
3. `cordova platform add ios` where `ios` can be changed to android or any of the platforms you want to support.

   Now the interesting part for you:
4. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media` - this will install the [Cordova Media Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media). Some Plugins you may need for your applications can be found over here -> [Cordova Plugins - the most important ones](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/cordova_plugins_pluginapis.md.html#Plugin%20APIs).

After you've finished your plugin adding, you need to `build` your project. This will copy all needed information and files into the single platform folders like ios or android for example. So run

5. `cordova build` to finish your setup process.

---

### **Important information for Plugins**

So after you installed those plugins, you can use the plugin commands which can be found inside the documentation for each plugin.

**Please note**: Most of the plugins require the `deviceReady()` event to be fired before they are available. Information for the `deviceReady()` event can be found here: [Cordova - DeviceReady Event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready).

---

### **Workflow for Audio-Recording**

So a workflow for your Audio-Recording could look something like this:

```
<head>
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(Media);
}
</script>
</head>
```

This requires the [cordova-console-plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console) (as we learned already: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console`) also to be installed before you see the console output.

```
// Record audio
//
function recordAudio() {
    var src = "myrecording.mp3";
    var mediaRec = new Media(src,
        // success callback
        function() {
            console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
        },

        // error callback
        function(err) {
            console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: "+ err.code);
        });

    // Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();
}
```

Where `recordAudio()` can be bound to a button with the `onclick="recordAudio()` attribute. The other function can be found inside the media documentation which was already linked.

If you need any further help, feel free to ask.

Comment: Very useful answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question. First, on iOS it should be .wav format. I've tested this, in the console I see that recording started, but there is no file. How to save recording?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Media Capture](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-media-capture) plugin to record audio. Use the captureAudio function.

```
navigator.device.capture.captureAudio
```